# Convert Lat/Long to X/Y for Albers Projection on US Map Image

Tags: c#, javascript, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to use C# or Javascript to convert Lat/Longs into X/Y Coordinates to position divs with CSS (left, top) onto a background image of a US map.  The standard map projection of the United States is an Albers Projection as seen below, but StackOverflow only has references for Lat/Long conversions that refer to basic Mercator projections.

Map:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Usa_counties_large.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUsa_counties_large.svg)

Map Size: 1460px width x 914px height

Lat/Long Samples:

```
LA: 34.0525, -118.2544
NY: 40.7582, -73.9679
DEN: 39.7512, -104.9975
```

Albers Projection Formula:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection

Here's my C# code so far:

```
int mapWidth = 1460; //US Map Width Px
int mapHeight = 914; //US Map Height Px

double lat = 34.0525; //LA Test Lat
double lng = -118.2544; //LA Test Long
double maxLat = 48.291667; //US Map North Lat (Approx)
double minLat = 22.46; //US Map South Lat (Approx)
double maxLng = -65.529722; //US Map East Long (Approx)
double minLng = -128.876944; //US Map West Long (Approx)

var n = (Math.Sin(minLat) + Math.Sin(maxLat)) * .5;
var a = n * (lng - minLng);
var c = Math.Pow(Math.Cos(minLat), 2) + ((2 * n) * Math.Sin(minLat));
var p = Math.Sqrt(c - ((2 * n) * Math.Sin(lat)));
var p2 = (n / Math.Sqrt(c - (2 * n) * Math.Sin(minLat))) / n;

result.x = p * Math.Sin(a); //Convert to Map Px ?
result.y = p2 - (p * Math.Cos(a)); //Convert to Map Px ?
```

**Questions:**

1) How do I adjust the Albers projection result to the factor in the Map Size (width/height in pixels) for X/Y pixel placement?

2) Is my Albers Math formula to C# code conversion correct?

3) What do the reference longitude (λ<sub>0</sub>) and reference latitude (φ<sub>0</sub>) refer to?   I guessed these meant the US Map West Long (minLng) and US Map North Lat (maxLat).

4) What do the standard parallels (φ<sub>1</sub> and φ<sub>2</sub>) refer to? I guessed these meant the US Map North Lat (maxLat) and US Map South Lat (minLat).

Comment: interesting projection and lets hope my boss wont ask me to do this.

Comment: haha, yeah if you search for United States maps, almost every one you find is an Albers type map projection, instead of Mercator.  It's the standard used by USGS, US Census Bureau, etc...  So this question would benefit a lot of people, and be a great reference for programmers.

Comment: whats this to do with mathematica?

Comment: do c# trig functions take angles in degrees?

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me post more than 2 links.  Here is the Wolfram formula link too.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlbersEqual-AreaConicProjection.html

Comment: Not sure George, any suggestions are welcome.  My latlngs are converted to decimals already if that helps.  I can also convert those into radians if needed.